# Setup ContainerLogV2 on an existing AKS

Tags: azure-aks

I have a question regarding setting up container log in an existing AKS instance. I have the following set up and have no luck seeing any logs in my AKS container logs (ContainerLogV2). ContainerLogV2 Schema is set up at the cluster level.

My .Net 6 Web APi uses Application Insights SDK as below

`builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();`

I can see requests and traces on my AI service.

This is what I have in appsettings.json

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "<Replace Me>"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My AKS is configured with LogAnalytics workspace and I can verify that as below:

```
"addonProfiles": {
    "omsagent": {
      "config": {
        "logAnalyticsWorkspaceResourceID": "/subscriptions/**/resourcegroups/**/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/my-aks-la"
      },
      "enabled": true,
      "identity": null
    }
  }
```

Can anyone please advise me what I might be missing here? I am happy to provide any more info. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContainerLogV2 schema needs to enabled through configmap. Here are the instructions to enable

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-logging-v2#enable-the-containerlogv2-schema-1

after applying the configmap, agent will get restarted in 2 to 3 mins and after that, you should see data in ContainerLogV2.

Comment: Nowhere in that linked document does it define what the config map name/namespace or data should be.  
Here's a good link that explains how to do it: https://schutten.cloud/post/transition-to-containerlogv2/